# Linux HP AIO scanner has blue tint (HPLIP, scanimage)

Tags: linux, command-line, scanner, sane, hplip

I have an Odroid with Ubuntu running and connected via LAN an HP LaserJet 3055 AIO.
I‘ve got the printer as well as the scanner basically running.
I used HPLIP and can now scan with e. g. scanimage via the commandline.

That is also exactly I wanna do. Because the scanning should be scripted, it should scan by a hardware button click to a specific location as pdf. That is also working, but now my issue:

If i scan via scanimage the scanned document has always a blue tint/coloring. If the scanner is connected via USB to an old Windows machine, there is no blue tint. So it isn‘t an hardware issue. It must be something the driver/sane is causing.
Or is not correcting - maybe the scan driver on Windows is doing some color profile correction automatically.

Anybody having the same problem and can help me?

Thanks
MrSandman

Comment: Perhaps a weird question, but do you have the latest firmware installed?

Comment: FW of the HP LJ 3055, yes it seems so. The latest version I was able to find online.

Comment: I just researched this myself. This also happens with my Fujitsu ScanSnap S1500. And similar complaints exist with Brother and Xerox scanners. As best I can tell, this is something that's done to increase contrast when scanning and the proprietary drivers compensate. For example, the Brother solution includes a color calibration that is uploaded to the drivers. If you can, I've seen fixes that modify the Blue color channel by adjusting Contrast to 38% and Gamma to 0.8. I'm going to try doing that with ImageMagick or other tool.